# Recording bluetooth headset audio in Nougat

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

So, I'm trying to record a wave file from and Bluetooth Headset.

This is what I use to record

```
 recorder = AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                BUFFER_SIZE)
```

And before starting recording I'm beginning and audio communication with my headset using

```
var am = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
am!!.mode = 0
am!!.isBluetoothScoOn = true
am!!.startBluetoothSco()
am!!.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
```

Well, it works wonders when recording in Android 6 (marshmallow), but when recording in Android 7 (nougat), it keeps recording from my phone's microphone and not the Bluetooth headset. Looking in the documentation, I didn't find anything regarding changes in Bluetooth SCO between versions. So.... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem when we tried to record a Bluetooth voice call. The problem was that the application started recording as soon as it received the telephony broadcast of the outgoing call, but the Bluetooth interface only connected a couple of milliseconds after the call has started.
We eventually solved this problem by applying a simple sleep before starting to record, and this fixed the problem.

Comment: We had the problem that in the begining of our application we recorded from the telfone mic. We solved this problem using a receiver 
        registerReceiver(mBluetoothScoReceiver, IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED)) , and just starting recording whe audio state was  AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED. Yet, it dosen't seens to solve the problema as we can only get a socket connection in nougat, but not a audio connection.